# On hover of list view's avatar it should change into checkbox

Tags: angularjs, listview, checkbox, angular-material, avatar

I have a requirement where I am facing problem.
The requirement is :
I have a LIST VIEW in which every LIST ITEM having an CIRCULAR AVATAR.

What I want? On hover of CIRCULAR AVATAR of LIST ITEM it should change into a checkbox to select this list item.

And Also all the LIST ITEM above and below should also show CHECKBOX instead of avatar for MULTI-SELECT of LIST ITEMS.

I am using angular-material and angularJs in my project.

For Demo purpose please check the link.
https://inbox.google.com/

Thanks in advance.

I am editing this post with code

```
<md-button  ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
    toggle
</md-button>
<div class="container" layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" class="md-whiteframe-4dp" flex md-component-id="left">
        <md-list flex>
            <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Tapplent Team</md-subheader>
            <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="setSelectedUser(user)">
              <img ng-src="{{user.avatar}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}" ng-show="toggle"/>
                <md-checkbox ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-hide="toggle">
                    Checkbox 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
                </md-checkbox>
              <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
                <h4>{{user.designation}}</h4>
                <p>{{user.technology}}</p>
              </div>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

Just to test I was doing with a button toggle that is basically Hiding and showing avatar and checkbox alternatively.

Comment: Have a checkbox and avatar in the same place for each list item. Use CSS hover to hide the avatar and show the checkbox when the user hovers over the avatar.

Comment: Use `ng-class` to hide the avatars if the number of selected items is greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks for reply. There is one more thing that is missing in requirement that on hover of avatar only this avatar should change into a checkbox and when I select this checkbox then all avatar should change into a checkbox for multi select

Comment: Also I would request you to please create a jsfiddle if possible. It would be a great help

Comment: The CSS hover is used to hide only one avatar. If you wrap the avatar and checkbox in a div, you do something like .wrapper:hover > img.avatar { display: none; } and do the same for the checkbox but show it. I will be busy for some time and may not be able to create an example today

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you managed to create a solution?

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure I am doing right way.
Also One issue I was not able to fix that on hover of avatar only that avatar should change to checkbox and once I clicked all the avatar (List Item) should change into checkbox for multi selection.

Comment: You should post what you've done so far. SO is about helping people not writing code for them.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

To hide the avatars and show the checkboxes on hover you can use CSS. Wrap the image and checkbox in a div and give it a class such as "avatarWrapper".

```
md-checkbox {
  display: none; /* Initially hide the checkbox */
}

/* When we hover over the wrapper, hide the avatar */
.avatarWrapper:hover > img.md-avatar {
  display: none;
}

/* When we hover over the wrapper, show the checkbox */
.avatarWrapper:hover > md-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

To hide all the avatars and show the checkboxes when at least one checkbox is checked, you can use `ng-class` to add a CSS class which will hide/show the appropriate elements.

**HTML:** `ng-class` will add class "atLeastOneSelected" if `atLeastOneSelected()` returns true.

I've added it to the list instead of to an element inside the `ng-repeat` because there is no need for it to check once per repeated element.

```
<md-list flex ng-class="{'atLeastOneSelected': atLeastOneSelected()}">
```

**JS:** You haven't provided your data or data structure so I've made up some. I've bound the checkboxes to `user.selected` with `ng-model`.

```
$scope.users = [
  {
    avatar: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/101/malecostume-512.png",
    name: "Matt",
    selected: false
  }, 
  {
    avatar: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/101/malecostume-512.png",
    name: "David",
    selected: false
  }, 
  {
    avatar: "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/101/malecostume-512.png",
    name: "Tom",
    selected: false
  }
];
```

Function to check if at least one user is selected. Returns true/false.

```
$scope.atLeastOneSelected = function() {
  $scope.users.some(function(user) {
    return user.selected === true;
  });
};
```

**CSS:**

```
.atLeastOneSelected img.md-avatar {
  display: none;
}

.atLeastOneSelected md-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jaydo/pen/ONrLBR)